# How to list all the names and ages associated with each activity

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains information about which people are taking part in each activity. Unfortunately there are up to a number of different places each piece of information can be put. That is one row can give information for many different people. The column names are as follows:

```
['Name', 'Activity', 'Name.0', 'Age.0', 'Activity.0', 'Name.1', 'Age.1', 'Activity.1', 'Name.2', 'Age.2', 'Activity.2', 'Name.3', 'Age.3',  'Activity.3', 'Name.4', 'Age.4', 'Activity.4']
```

For each Activity, I want to list all the people who are associated with it and their ages (if that information is provided). Ultimately I want to make one table per Activity. How can I do that?

It feels like I need to first need to deal with all the .* column names and then groupby Activity somehow but I am not sure how to do it.

Here is some anonymized data outputted using `df.sample(5).to_dict()`.

```
{'Activity': {0: 'Audi', 1: 'Carn', 2: 'Pop-', 3: 'Samb', 4: 'Pre-'},
 'Activity.0': {0: 'Samb', 1: 'Pre-', 2: 'nan', 3: 'Samb', 4: 'Pre-'},
 'Activity.1': {0: 'Samb', 1: 'Audi', 2: 'nan', 3: 'Samb', 4: 'nan'},
 'Activity.2': {0: 'Pre-', 1: 'Audi', 2: 'nan', 3: 'nan', 4: 'nan'},
 'Activity.3': {0: 'nan', 1: 'Carn', 2: 'nan', 3: 'nan', 4: 'nan'},
 'Activity.4': {0: 'nan', 1: 'Carn', 2: 'nan', 3: 'nan', 4: 'nan'},
 'Age.0': {0: '18+', 1: 'Under 5', 2: '11', 3: '11', 4: 'Under 5'},
 'Age.1': {0: '11', 1: 'Under 5', 2: '11', 3: 17, 4: '18+'},
 'Age.2': {0: '11', 1: '18+', 2: 'nan', 3: '18+', 4: 'nan'},
 'Age.3': {0: 'Under 5', 1: '18+', 2: 'nan', 3: 'nan', 4: 'nan'},
 'Age.4': {0: 'nan', 1: '18+', 2: 'nan', 3: 'nan', 4: 'nan'},
 'Name': {0: 'Jess', 1: 'Tama', 2: 'Beki', 3: 'Havi', 4: 'Dror'},
 'Name.0': {0: 'Sam ', 1: 'Lila', 2: 'nan', 3: 'Joel', 4: 'Emil'},
 'Name.1': {0: 'Zipp', 1: 'Marg', 2: 'nan', 3: 'Solo', 4: 'Ari '},
 'Name.2': {0: 'Reub', 1: 'Joan', 2: 'nan', 3: 'Sami', 4: 'nan'},
 'Name.3': {0: 'Shev', 1: 'John', 2: 'nan', 3: 'nan', 4: 'nan'},
 'Name.4': {0: 'nan', 1: 'Edwa', 2: 'nan', 3: 'nan', 4: 'nan'}}
```

For this example, let's take the activity called 'Audi'.  The only people doing this are 'Jess' (no age), 'Marge' (under 5) and 'Joan' (18+).  For the activity 'Samb', the people associated with it are 'Havi' (no age), 'Sam' (18+), 'Joel' (11),'Zipp' (11) and 'Solo' (17).   I would like the same thing for each of the activities.

Comment: Add expected output for above data

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar example added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you:

```
activities = {}
# function for Activity, Name
def add_details_for_activity(row):
    global activities
    if pd.notna(row[1]) and pd.notna(row[0]) and row[1] != 'nan' and row[0] != 'nan':
        if activities.get(row[0]) is not None:
            activities[row[0]].append(row[1])
        else:
            activities[row[0]] = [row[1]]

# function for Activity.#, Name.#, age.#   
def add_details_for_activities(row):
    global activities
    if pd.notna(row[1]) and pd.notna(row[0]) and row[1] != 'nan' and row[0] != 'nan':
        if activities.get(row[0]) is not None:
            if pd.notna(row[2]) and row[2] != 'nan':
                activities[row[0]].append((row[1], row[2]))
            else:
                activities[row[0]].append(row[1])
        else:
            print(row[0])
            if pd.notna(row[2]) and row[2] != 'nan':
                activities[row[0]] = [(row[1], row[2])]
            else:
                activities[row[0]] = [row[1]]


df[['Activity', 'Name']].apply(add_details_for_activity, axis = 1)
for i in range(5):
    df[['Activity.'+str(i), 'Name.'+str(i), 'Age.'+str(i)]].apply(add_details_for_activities, axis = 1)
```

Sample output is:

```
{'Audi': ['Jess', ('Marg', 'Under 5'), ('Joan', '18+')],
 'Carn': ['Tama', ('John', '18+'), ('Edwa', '18+')],
 'Pop-': ['Beki'],
 'Samb': ['Havi',
  ('Sam ', '18+'),
  ('Joel', '11'),
  ('Zipp', '11'),
  ('Solo', 17)],
 'Pre-': ['Dror', ('Lila', 'Under 5'), ('Emil', 'Under 5'), ('Reub', '11')]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach: uses itertools groupby, sorted and defaultdict to get the final result

```
from itertools import groupby
fn = lambda x: x[0].split('.')[-1]
s = sorted(data.items(), key = fn)
R = []
groups=[]    
#data must be sorted before the groupby function is invoked
for k, g in groupby(s, key = fn):
    m = list(g)
#this part fetches Activity and Name,
#since they have no numbers attached to them
#separates them, zips them, and assign to A
    if len(m)==1:
        [R.append(r) for r in m]
    else:
 #here we work on the rest that have numbers attached to the keys
   #we zip them as well, and append to groups
        first = [(i[0].split('.')[0],*i[-1].values()) for i in m]
        second = zip(*first)
        [groups. append(i) for i in second]
    A = list(zip(*[i[-1].values() for i in R]))
#all data in one place
groups.extend(A)

#get rid of 'noise'
groups = [i for i in groups if i not in [('Activity', 'Age', 'Name'),('nan', 'nan', 'nan')]]

from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for k,*v in groups:
    d[k].append(v)

del (d['nan'])

defaultdict(list,
        {'Samb': [['18+', 'Sam '],
          ['11', 'Joel'],
          ['11', 'Zipp'],
          [17, 'Solo'],
          ['Havi']],
         'Pre-': [['Under 5', 'Lila'],
          ['Under 5', 'Emil'],
          ['11', 'Reub'],
          ['Dror']],
         'Audi': [['Under 5', 'Marg'], ['18+', 'Joan'], ['Jess']],
         'Carn': [['18+', 'John'], ['18+', 'Edwa'], ['Tama']],
         'Pop-': [['Beki']]})
```

Comment: If my dataframe is called df, how do I call your code?

Comment: You export your df as a dict